Invalid xml characters <> in tag
I have an xml file. For example:
<tag>test ,test <adjs@gmail.com></tag>

Obviously the XML is not valid. What can I do using python to remove all the '<','>' characters that are not tags?
I tried reading it as text, but I can't remove just the extra characters without touching the tags.
import re

# Legge il file XML come testo
with open('file.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    xml_content = file.read()

# Definisce una regex per trovare il contenuto dei tag e rimuovere i caratteri "<" e ">"
# La regex cercherà qualsiasi cosa tra ">" e "<", che rappresenta il contenuto tra i tag XML
def remove_invalid_characters(xml_text):
    return re.sub(r'>([^<]+)<', lambda match: '>' + match.group(1).replace('<', '').replace('>', '') + '<', xml_text)

# Applica la funzione al contenuto XML
cleaned_xml_content = remove_invalid_characters(xml_content)

# Scrive il contenuto corretto su un nuovo file (o sovrascrive lo stesso file)
with open('file_cleaned.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(cleaned_xml_content)

print("Caratteri '<' e '>' non validi rimossi dal contenuto dei tag.")


Fix it at the source.

How are you reading the xml file?

i add at the post

@xcostal How would you tell if something needs removing and is not a part XML syntax? This may be obvious in this simple case, but once the file gets big enough it's pretty much impossible. As the common saying about broken xml goes, "Garbage in, garbage out". The correct approach is to make sure wherever the input comes from, it is not giving you broken xml.

Generally, processing input that conforms to a grammar Y requires first defining the exact rules for Y and then writing a custom parser for Y. The fact that your language Y is very similar to XML doesn't change this.

By far the best solution is to fix the problem at the source -- only create, and demand that others only create, well-formed XML.  If you decide to compromise on that well-established best practice -- and, again, you should not --  see the duplicate link for techniques for dealing with bad "XML"

You could use BeautifulSoup to parse the input as XML, and then cleanup the normalized XML as needed.
For instance:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup
invalid_doc = '<tag>test ,test <adjs@gmail.com></tag>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(invalid_doc, "xml")
print(soup.prettify())

returns valid XML that you can work with:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag>
 test ,test
 <adjs>
  @gmail.com&gt;
 </adjs>
</tag>

and then you could relatively easily replace the adjs element with the email as text:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup
invalid_doc = '<tag>test ,test <adjs@gmail.com></tag>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(invalid_doc, "xml")
for child in soup.tag.children:
    if not isinstance(child, str):
      email = child.name + child.text.replace(">", "").replace("<","")
      child.replace_with(email)
print(soup.prettify())

returns:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag>
 test ,test
 adjs@gmail.com
</tag>


Hi, I have about 70,000 lines, how can I then delete the new tag that is created with soup? Thanks

I have no idea what you mean.

Your regex matches all tags, not just the invalid ones. If you want to target only broketed expressions which contain . or @ (for example) then write a regex which matches only those.
Here's a simpler one-pass solution which uses fileinput to write back to the original file.
import re
from fileinput import input as fileinput

for line in fileinput('file.xml', inplace=True):
    print(re.sub(r'<[^<>.@]*[.@][^<>]*>', '', line), end='')

The end='' is to prevent print from adding a second newline; the line already has one when you read it from the file.
Demo: https://ideone.com/bD1ec0
